# Asp.Net Core MVC - Can I move Identity and DataAccess to class library

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET Core MVC Web application with Individual User Account authentication (Identity).

The template has created one Web project, with a whole bunch of folders, including a "Data" folder which has the migrations for the Identity schema, and ApplicationDbContext.

Now, I have some other projects alongside the web app which will need to consume the data.  I don't want them to reference the web project for obvious reasons.

And ideally I don't want my web project to depend directly on EF.

Can I move the data access into a separate class library?  And if so, how!?

Comment: Yes you can move them. create new projects and transfer code to those projects. make sure to include any dependencies/references needed. You can then add the separated projects as dependencies to projects that need them (including web app). You can create abstraction of data access to add layer between EF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, check out the Dev branch on https://github.com/MachUpskillingFY17/JabbR-Core  we just moved all data into a separate library including identity. Its still quite a work in progress, but it absolutely works.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Adam!  Is there anything to do to keep migrations working in the new project or is it literally just moving the Migrations folder over?

Comment: Thanks Adam I got it working.  I did have a little issue with Migrations not working from the CLI.  It gave me a nice error message pointing me to this https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#targeting-class-library-projects-is-not-supported  So I was able to workaround it by using the --startup-project parameter to point to the main web project.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Adam for your reply. I would also like to do  the same. However, I saw in the Startup.cs of your WebApp in ConfigureServices that you still reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore which makes your Web app dependant to that package. Would it be possible to move that part of the configuration into a DAL class library for example in order to follow SOLID rules and have only my DAL taking care of EF interactions? Thank you

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a class library projects.
2. Move the content from `corewebproject/data` to class library projects.
3. Add following from nuget:

   - Entity Framework
   - `AspNetCore.Identity`
   - `AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework`
   - `Microsoft.entityframeworkcore.SqlServer`
   - `Microsoft.entityframeworkcore.Tools`
   - `Microsoft.entityframeworkcore.Tools.Dotnet`
4. Build class library projects.
5. Add as reference to your web project.
6. Change reference in startup `contextdb` file location.
7. If you want to change you sql server from `localdb` change `defaultconnection` in `appsettings`.
8. Add reference related files.
9. Build solutions.
10. Go to nuget package manager console and select your project.
11. Run next commands:

    - 'Remove-Migration'. it will remove some file including snapmodel file
    - Add-Migrations "Name"
    - update database
12. Check you database: you can see upadated db with aspnetcore individual account related tables.

!!! Enjoy !!!!

Comment: Most of the Nuget packages  names in the answer has changed but names are still similar. This is still the best answer